Checking if object already exists in another array before adding it
I have an array of objects (opciones) and another array (visibles) where im trying to add the objects that are supposed to show up.
 function next(ev, next) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    setToggle(next.siguiente);
    let element = document.getElementById(next.siguiente);
    opciones.map(
      (opcion) => opcion.id === next.siguiente && visibles.push(opcion)
    );
  }

Next is the current object i'm passing onClick/submit.
SetToggle: i set visibility of the component i want to show.
next.siguiente - the next component ID that has to show up after this function is finished.
opciones - my initial array of objects
**visibles **- the array where i add the selected objects
and in my opciones.map function i'm trying to detect if the next component ID exists in the opciones array i want to push it into visibles array.
It works but im obviously getting duplicates the way i'm doing it right now.
So pretty much siguiente would be the ID of the next object / component i want to display.
How would i be able to check if visibles already has the added object before i add it again?
i tried something like:
 function next(ev, next) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    setToggle(next.siguiente);
    let element = document.getElementById(next.siguiente);
    if (visibles.includes(next)) {
      console.log("already exists");
    } else {
      opciones.map(
        (opcion) => opcion.id === next.siguiente && visibles.push(opcion)
      );
    }
  }


but it doesn't really work. I'm getting duplicated keys when displaying the list and it keeps adding to the array.
Any help or recommendation in general to improve this would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

I am assuming this is React code? It seems to contain JSX which suggests it could be React, but it also has direct DOM access which suggest it's not (or probably React code written by a React newby). Please clarify and tag the question accordingly. Also please provide the relevant component code like e.g. the toggle state (since there is setToggle() I am assuming that's component state). Furthermore, for a minimal reproducible example you could minimize the amount of data in the options as it is irrelevant for the question.

Hello! Deleted the extra code.
Also yes, this is react and I’m pretty new to react been practicing for 3 weeks so I still have some vanilla js habits lol

Also the setToggle and Toggle aren’t really relevant to my question, I only want ro know how to check if the object exists in the “visible” array before I add the obj. Toggle is just so I can add visibility to X component and it works fine I don’t have problem with that’s. Just the last part of the code when I’m mapping through the “opciones”

function next(actual) {
    setToggle(actual.siguiente);
    opciones.forEach((opcion) => {
        if (opcion.id === actual.siguiente) {
            const exists = visibles.some((visible) => visible.id === opcion.id);
            if (!exists) {
                visibles.push(opcion)
            }
        }
    });
}

Used vikashraj144's answer for reference.
His function added the entire Array of objects into the new array of objects without duplicating the objects.
I needed to select and object and check if it already exists in the array before adding it.

const sourceArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 2, name: "Jane" },
  { id: 3, name: "Doe" },
];

const targetArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 4, name: "Smith" },
];

const addUniqueObjects = (source, target) => {
  source.forEach((sourceObj) => {
    const exists = target.some((targetObj) => targetObj.id === sourceObj.id);
    if (!exists) {
      target.push(sourceObj);
    }
  });
};

addUniqueObjects(sourceArray, targetArray);

console.log(targetArray);


This works but adds every object if not repeated in the second array. I just want to add specific objects to the second array not all at the same time :D how would i modify this to add just the passed object?
